# Otto EventBus: Event fired multiple times

Tags: java, android, otto

I am using the Otto event bus in my android application and have the problems that identical events get fired multiple times (`event.hashCode()` returns the same integer). The code I use to fire the events looks like this (simplified):

```
public class MyFragment extends MyCustomFragment {
    @Inject Bus eventBus;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        App.getComponent(getActivity()).inject(this); // use dagger to inject the event bus
    }


    // called from within `onOptionsItemSelected`
    public void handleOptionsItemXy() {
        AlertDialog.Builder a = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            // ...
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_label_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // EVENT IS FIRED HERE
                    Log.d("INFO", "This log message is only displayed once!");
                    eventBus.post(new Event(EVENT_DATA));
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I then have a class to handle the event like this, which is created in my `MainActivity.onCreate`:

```
public class StuffManager {
    @Inject Bus bus;

    public StuffManager(Activity ctx) {
        App.getComponent(ctx).inject(this);
        bus.register(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void manageStuff(Event event) {
        Log.d("SYNC", "Some event needs to be managed");
        Log.d("SYNC", "HASH: " + event.hashCode());
    }
}
```

The log message is only shown once and the event is only ever created at that specific location. It appears that there is something unexpected happening *inside* the `.post` method provided by the event bus.

How does this happen? What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: what makes you believe the event is getting fired multiple times?

Comment: I have edited the main post to answer your question.

Comment: are you sure you don't simply have multiple instances of `StuffManager` ?

Comment: also otto will match listeners based on the param type of the annotated method, so you should be more descriptive than `Event` for the event class name otherwise you could have listeners all over the place... unless that's also simplified for purposes of example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was not that the event was actually **fired** multiple times, but that the handler was invoked multiple times. As seen in the code above, the `bus.register` method is called everytime I create the object; because of the activities lifecycle, this happened multiple times, causing the handler to be invoked multiple times.

Thanks to [jonk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349624/jonk) for leading me on the right path.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case :P glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening with me too. I have some fragments using the same fragment class saying StuffFragment and I create two instances of StuffFragment. So because I subscribed Otto bus in StuffFragment class. The post method happens once and the actual event is fired once. But since there are two instances so it will do the same stuff when receiving the event which looks like we received two events.

Comment: Answers are to propose solutions, please use comments to elaborate on the problem.